# Showing and hiding button with custom animation

Tags: swift, animation, button, uiappearance

Now I'm having such animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
   self.scrollToTopBtn.alpha = self.isVisible(self.searchBar.searchBar) ? 0 : 0.6
}
```

Button is located in bottom-right corner of screen. I want her to appear moving from right to left and dissapear moving from left to right.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to achieve this is:

1.- Lets say that `let buttonWidth` is the width of your `scrollToTopBtn` `UIButton`.

2.- Put your `scrollToTopBtn` in the bottom-right corner of screen, but all the way right out of the screen bounds. This will be your initial state for the button.

3.- When you want it to appear, just call following function:

**Swift 2**

```
func showButton() {
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, animations: { () -> Void in
      self.scrollToTopBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.scrollToTopBtn.transform, -buttonWidth, 0)
      }, nil)
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
func showButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.scrollToTopBtn.transform = self.scrollToTopBtn.transform.translatedBy(x: -buttonWidth, y: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

4.- If you want it to disappear:

**Swift 2**

```
func hideButton() {
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35, animations: { () -> Void in
      self.scrollToTopBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.scrollToTopBtn.transform, buttonWidth, 0)
      }, nil)
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
func hideButton() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.scrollToTopBtn.transform = self.scrollToTopBtn.transform.translatedBy(x: buttonWidth, y: 0)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

> Notice that a good practice may be to create the button in runtime, adding it to the hierarchy when needed and then removing it when done using it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways to do it. The easiest would be setting frame of the button. Something like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
    self.scrollToTopBtn.alpha = self.isVisible(self.searchBar.searchBar) ? 0 : 0.6
    let superViewWidth = self.scrollToTopBtn.superview!.bounds.size.width
    let buttonWidth = self.scrollToTopBtn.frame.size.width

    if(self.isVisible(self.searchBar.searchBar)) { // move it off of the view (towards right)
        self.scrollToTopBtn.frame.origin.x = superViewWidth + buttonWidth
    }
    else { // bring it back to it's position
        self.scrollToTopBtn.frame.origin.x = 10 // or whatever the normal x value for the button is
    }
}
```

#### The better way to do it

The better way would be to animate the constraint constant. Here's how you could do it:

First create an outlet for the constraint in your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Go to Interface builder and connect the button's leading constraint to `buttonLeadingConstraint` outlet.

Now you can animate it like this:

```
if(self.isVisible(self.searchBar.searchBar)) { // move it off the screen
    self.buttonLeadingConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.width + 10
}
else {
    self.buttonLeadingConstraint.constant = 10 // or whatever the normal value is
}

// Now animate the change
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Note that you set the constant on constraint **before** you call `animateWithDuration`, and inside the animations block, you only need to call `layoutIfNeeded' on the parent view.

Comment: My favourite is to set the frame with constraints but animate using the `transform` property.

Comment: Since AutoLayout is generally the superior way to do the UI, mine is animate constraint constants, keeps things consistent through out. but to each his own :-)

Comment: Animating constraints works fine when the layout is not too complex or when you want the other views to react to the change, otherwise, animating a constraint might break the layout, so it's better to let AutoLayout handle the positioning and do animations with transforms.

Comment: you can animate most of the cases with changes to `constant` of a constraint, i.e. always safe (constraint's can't break). If a constraint might break, then you need to be careful not to break it. mixing transforms with auto-layout _can_ create hard to debug layout issues. Sticking to one system makes one more adept and thereby less prone to bugs.